Need Coldcard CLI doc clarification
I'm looking at the documentation for the Coldcard CLI and I'm a little confused as to what specifically the -p, --path TEXT command does. In the documentation, it says the following:

% ckcc msg --help Usage: ckcc msg [OPTIONS] MESSAGE
Sign a short text message
Options:   -p, --path TEXT  Derivation for key to use
-v, --verbose Include fancy ascii armour
-j, --just-sig   Just the signature itself, nothing more
--help           Show this message and exit.
% ckcc msg "Hello world" Hello world
mp2SHbLDr5hg4tvKhaZGKzkf3GmzAuQCz1
H3wh0RIKoIcyRShkbMm5SbVoKaeMYlf4up7dvVfvP1c1N5FEXoBcjiiTNxR88ybpW3XlujHGhyCvy2/hnMtSE+c=

Let's say I have a transaction with a single input with the path m/84'/0/0/1/0. If I were to, say, command --path m/5', would that then sign the transaction with the PRIVATE KEY at m/5' or would it sign it with m/5'/84'/0/0/1/0?
Thanks,
Myles

Based on the behaviour of their test suite, it should sign with the key at m/5', and not attempt to coerce it into a prefix for a standard path.
